# How to return data from from 2 criteria in the same column while selecting columns from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables;
T.1- Item_master that contains columns: upc_ean, description, store_pos_department, item_id. 
T.2- Alternate_categories that contains columns: category, item_id.

I am trying to create a statement that gives me the upc_ean, and description, from t.1 and the category from t.2 where upc_ean from t.1 has a category number of 11 and any other number assigned to it from the category column in t.2
I only want the results indicated by *** lines.

```
upc_ean         description                        category
013130006989    CRM OF RICE 14Z                     7
016000263444    GM CINN CHEX                        7
016000264182    GM RICE CHEX PP                     7
016000274730    GM CHEX CHOCOLATE                   7
**016000275270  GM HNY NUT CHEERIOS 12.25Z          11**
**016000275270  GM HNY NUT CHEERIOS 12.25Z          6**
016000275287    GM CHEERIOS 18Z                     11
016000275317    GM HNY NUT CHEX 13.8Z               7
016000275584    GM CHEX CORN 14Z                    7
016000275591    GM CHEX RICE 12.08Z                 7
016000275645    GM CHEERIOS 14Z                     6
016000406087    GM CHEX VAN                         7
016000444980    GM CHEX GF GRAN HNYNUT              7
016000444997    GM CHEX GF GRAN BRYALM              7
016000486416    CHEX GF OATMEAL ORIG                7
016000486423    CHEX GF OATMEAL MAPLE BRNW SGR      7
016000486430    CHEX GF OATMEAL APPLE CINN          7
**016000487727  GM CHERRIOS                         11**
**016000487727  GM CHERRIOS                         6**
016000487895    GM CHEX CINN                        7
016000487925    GM CHEX HONEY NUT                   7
016000487932    GM CHEX CHOC                        7
016000487949    GM CHEX RICE                        7
016000487963    GM CHEX CORN                        7
016000487987    GM CHEX VANILLA                     7
**030000010402  QUAKER OATS OLD FSHN 42Z            11**
**030000010402  QUAKER OATS OLD FSHN 42Z            6**
030000012000    QUAKER OATS OLD FSHN QUICK 42 OZ    6
**038000016110  KELL SP K 12Z                       11**
**038000016110  KELL SP K 12Z                       6**
038000076480    KELL SP K VAN ALMND                 6
038000102653    KELL SPEC K CHOC ALMND              6
038000113277    KELL SP K PRO CBS CRNCH             6
038000113284    KELL SP K GLUTEN FREE               6
```

This the the statement I used for the results above, I have tried several variations and cannot get the desired results:

```
select a.upc_ean, a.description, b.category from item_master a
inner join alternate_categories b
on a.item_id=b.item_Id
where b.category in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12')
and store_pos_department=556
order by a.upc_ean
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to reformat this question so it can be read easier. This should include sample data (in tabular format), and your expected results. Also include any code you have tried and why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but it should be close to what you're looking for:

```
SELECT upc, description, count(*) over(partition by alt) as catcount FROM
( 
 SELECT i.upc, a.description, '1' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories1 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '2' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories2 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '3' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories3 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '4' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories4 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '5' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories5 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '6' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories6 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '7' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories7 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '8' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories8 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '9' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories9 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '10' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories10 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '11' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories11 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
  UNION
  SELECT i.upc, a.description, '12' as alt
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories12 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
)
WHERE catcount > 1 
and EXISTS(
  SELECT * from
  FROM item_master i
  JOIN alternate_categories11 a
  ON i.upc = a.upc
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inner join on item_master

```
select upc from item_master  a, 
inner join item_master b on a.upc = b.upc 
where a.alternate_category  = '11'
and b. a.alternate_category !='11
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use a group by with a having condition on it.  For the specific data you showed you would only want the 1234 upc correct?

So you could do the following:

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (UPC INT, AlternateCategory INT)
INSERT INTO @Table (UPC, AlternateCategory)
    VALUES (1234,5),(1234,11),(2345,5),(2456,11)


SELECT Upc
FROM
    @Table
GROUP BY
    UPC
HAVING
    SUM(IIF(AlternateCategory = 11,1,0)) > 0
    AND SUM(IIF(AlternateCategory <> 11,1,0)) > 0
```